# Drupal CKEditor 5 custom plugin focus stays on toolbar button after clicking

Tags: plugins, drupal, focus, ckeditor5

I've created a custom CKE5 plugin that is working as it should with one exception. The plugin uses the insertContent method to insert an inline html tag wrapping some editable content. **BUT** after clicking the button in the toolbar, the focus stays on the button instead of changing back to the editor window. So if a user, after clicking my plugin button, hits "enter" on the keyboard, it adds another instance of the inserted tag and content. If the user hits "tab", the focus changes to the editor window as it should, including on the correct selection. How, in the plugin code, do I get the focus to change to the editor window after the button is clicked, just like all other buttons in the toolbar?

FYI, the insertion is after a document selection, without removing a document selection.

The execute code for the command is:

```
    export default class InsertMyTagCommand extends Command {
      execute() {
        const { model } = this.editor;
        const anch = model.document.selection.anchor;

        model.change((writer) => {
          const mytag = writer.createElement('myTag');
          writer.append(' Click here, select all, and paste/type new content ', mytag);
          model.insertContent(mytag, anch, -0);
          writer.setSelection(mytag, 'in');
        });
      }
```